# Understanding $D_n ⊂ O_2(R) ⊂ E(R^2 ) ⊂ S(R^2 )$ and their elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to get a grip of these groups:  $D_n ⊂ O_2(R) ⊂ E(R^2 ) ⊂ S(R^2 )$
where $D_n$ is best understood by me, but how about these other ones? Can you people give me an intuïtive explanation if their elements, order of their elements and so on?

Specifically $O_2(R) , E(R^2)$. Now I'm told that $O_2(R)$ can have elements of any finite order, can you give me an example? And what is $E(R^2)$ actually

Comment: This is a rather broad question, and the answers are rather involved. (Indeed, $O_2(R)$ has orders of any given finite order, as well as elements of infinite order.) I'd suggest editing this question to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Alright, edited

Comment: The notation $S(\Bbb R^2)$ isn't standard to my knowledge---is it the special linear group? (This is usually denoted $SL(2, \Bbb R)$ or $SL_2(\Bbb R)$.)

Comment: @Travis As $S(\Bbb R^2)$ contains $E(\Bbb R^2)$, I would assume it's the symmetric group of $\Bbb R^2$. I'm not sure, but I can't imagine any other $\Bbb R^2$-related groups that contain the two-dimensional Euclidean group. I know in Berger's *Geometry*, he comments on this inclusion.

Comment: Oops, I really meant to write something like $SL(2, \Bbb R) \ltimes \Bbb R^2$, the group of affine, volume-preserving transformations. It's certainly plausible that it's the symmetric group on the points of $\Bbb R^2$, but unlike all the other groups in the list, it doesn't preserve any geometry at all.

Comment: @Travis Indeed, it's definitely the odd man out! I only suggest it because in Berger's *Geometry*, he takes a second to write the affine group $GA(X)$ of a space $X$ as the intersection $A(X, X) \cap \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ of the set of affine maps from a space to itself, with the symmetric group of the space.

Answer (score 1):

The *orthogonal group* $O_2(\Bbb R)$ is the group of all linear transformations $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ that preserve length; these are precisely the rotations about the origin (which themselves comprise the *special orthgoonal group* $SO_2(R)$) and the reflections across a line through the origin. One can show that if we identify a linear transformation $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ with its matrix (w.r.t. the standard representation), a matrix $A$ is in $O_2(\Bbb R)$ iff $A^T A = I_2$.

A rotation by an angle $\alpha$ followed by a rotation by an angle $\beta$ is the same thing as a rotation by the angle $\alpha + \beta$, so for positive integers $k$, the rotation by $\frac{2 \pi}{k}$ radians has order $k$ (in fact, such an element and any reflection together generate a copy of the dihedral group $D_{2k}$ of order $2k$). Rotations by an irrational multiple of $\pi$ have infinite order. All reflections have order $2$.

The group $E_2(\Bbb R)$ is the *Euclidean group*, which consists of all *affine* transformations that preserve length. These are precisely the affine transformations ${\bf x} \mapsto A {\bf x} + b$, where $A \in O_2(\Bbb R)$ and $b \in \Bbb R^2$. The composition rule shows that $E_2(\Bbb R)$ is a semidirect product: $E_2(\Bbb R) = O_2(\Bbb R) \ltimes \Bbb R^2$.